# Unable to set RequestUri of HttpResponseMessage in Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am calling 2 APIs (one orignal and other mock) using HttpClient.

So if the URL of the API call is `https://something.com/abc/xyz`, when I POST to this url in the response the `RequestMessage.RequestUri` has a certain value i.e `https://something.com/mno/eee?key=asdad`.

To replicate this behaviour I have a web api controller setup -

```
public class JqPay2Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("donotcare")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DoNotCare()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:3232/mno/eee?key=asdad");
        var contentStr = $"donotcare";
        var res = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(contentStr),
            RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
        };
        return res;
    }
}
```

Which my application will call in mock mode and I expect to see the same value in the `RequestMessage.RequestUri` property.

But I do not see it, instead I see `https://something.com/abc/xyz` when I expect to see `https://localhost:3232/mno/eee?key=asdad`.

I am not sure how this works? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("donotcare")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoNotCare()
{
    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3232/"); 

       var request = new HttpRequestMessage
         (HttpMethod.Post, "abc/xyz");  // or "mno/eee?key=asdad"

       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

       return response;
    }
}
```

do you have an API end point with the route ["abc/xyz"] somewhere in your code base? or are you actually trying to hit a live external api? if so, change the client.BaseAddress to "https://something.com/api". also, after HttpMethod.Post, change "abc/xyz" to whatever their actual end point is. eg.

```
[HttpPost, Route("abc/xyz")]
public string DoNotCareEndPoint()
{
    return "https://localhost:3232/mno/eee?key=asdad";
}
```

Let me know what this returns, and I can try and help you further.